# PIP not installing to virtualenv directory

Tags: python, installation, packages, virtualenv, pip

I am attempting to install django to a virtualenv that already exists.

Following the instructions listed on the pip-install website [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html), I ran the following from SSH.

```
name@server:~$ . myenv.env/bin/activate
(myenv.env)nam@server:~$ pip install django
```

However at the bottom of the installation, I am seeing this:

```
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django': Permission denied
```

It appears that it is trying to install it to the global directory. I do not have sudo privileges. Am I doing something wrong here?

Update:
$PATH = /var/django/myenv.env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: Does it work correctly for other packages?  Do you have the same problem if you use `easy_install`?

Comment: Same problem with other packages. And I believe easy_install requires sudo and would install into the global directory.

Comment: Nope, setting up a virtualenv gets you easy_install as well as pip.  You can type `which easy_install` to see if you're using your virtualenv or the system one.

Comment: Actually, are you sure you're running pip from inside the virtualenv?  What does `which pip` yield?  And do you see `pip` inside `myenv.env/bin/`?

Comment: I do see pip inside of myenv.env/bin/. I just tried "activating" my env again, and despite being in that mode, "which pip" and "which easy_install" both return "usr/local/bin/pip" and "usr/bin/easy_install" respectively.

Comment: What does your `$PATH` look like (please update the question rather than posting that as a comment)?  Also, what if you explicitly run `myenv.env/bin/pip install ...`?

Comment: I updated the question with the path. And I was originally trying that but it says "bad interpreter: No such file or directory". The other strange thing is even though I'm typing myenv.env/bin/pip, it is saying myenv.env/bin/python: bad interpreter

Comment: Ist there a `myenv.env/bin/python` at all?

Comment: Yes there is, and if I try to execute the python in that folder it successfully starts interactive python.

Comment: Could you try to create a virtualenv with another name, such like "ve1" and try it from there?

Comment: I was able to install requirements  explicitly using pip from venv/bin/pip3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for a year late answer! I had the same problem and fixed it, I don't know if you changed the name of a directory after creating the virtual environment, I did though. If so then here's what I did.

1.) `deactivate` your v-env. After the fix you need to restart the v-env, so might as well `deactivate` now. right?

2.) Now, since we created the v-env in a different path, we have to change the static path variables in these files.

To get pip working you don't need to do this, but I still do.
`bin/activate`,
`bin/activate.csh`,
`bin/activate.fish`

`bin/pip`,
`bin/pip2`,
`bin/pip2.7`

`bin/easy_install`,
`bin/easy_install2.7`

3.) To get pip working, you must correct the python interpreter in the pip file, this as well has a static interpreter location set by virtualenv in the creation process.

4.) To get easy_install working? You guessed it, fix the interpreter location.

I hope this helped for any people reading this in the future. Sorry OP, for being late.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly it. In my case I was able to just re-create the virtualenv from scratch and that solved it.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: I'm so glad to finally find an answer.  For me, using sed in the venv folder made the job a lot easier.  Something like `grep -rli '/path/to/old/env/bin' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/\/path\/to\/old\/env\/bin/\/path\/to\/new\/env\/bin/g' @`.[source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20721292/3006854)

Comment: You say, "To get pip working, you must correct the python interpreter in the pip file", where and how is this done?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem.

I deleted the virtual environment and created a new one, which solved the problem.

Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but since it's the only one...

Answer (score 1):

Well without administrative privileges you're very limited on what you are able to do. If you are not allowed to elevate yourself  or ask for privileges, the best way I found to go about that would be to create another environment, make a requirements.txt file, download all the packages you need to your machine( django ) that would also be located in your requirements file and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `sudo pip` will call global pip and not pip in your virtualenv. Activate/Workon your environment then just call `pip`, not `sudo pip`, this may fix your issue, as it did mine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. In my case the reason was that the created virtual env was for python2.7 (the default) but I was using pip3 to install a package. pip3 was not present in my virtualenv so it defaulted to the global one. For me the fix was to use

```
virtualenv flask --python=python3
```

to create the env.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same problem caused by renaming of user. 
Crispy's answer is totally right. And my solution may be more convenient.

**setps:**
1. Enter your virtual environment's bin path, such as `cd ~/virenv_dir/bin`
2. Rename all files under this directory using sed command. `sed -i 's/old_name/new_name/' *`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had defined two aliases (to overcome some other issue on the default python version):

```
alias pip='/usr/bin/pip3'
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

And this was causing the same symptoms:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
```

Removing the aliases solved the issue (before or after creating the virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

In may case I had upgraded my main python version and this was not reflected in the virtualenv. So to upgrade pip, make sure your virtualenv is activated, then run

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```